# tcpreplay does not work

Tags: security, sniffing, tcpdump

I have a problem with tcpreplay and hostapd, this is my scenario: a client connects to `172.24.1.91/OPEN` and `/CLOSE` and processes a GET request to a server that lights up or down a Led. I made a Java client that does a `/OPEN` and `/CLOSE` request every second and it fully works.
I sniffed get requests with `tcpdump`:

```
sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 host 172.24.1.1 -w test.pcap
```

And after running the client I use `tcpreplay`:

```
sudo tcpreplay -i wlan0 test.pcap
```

But my led does not blink while running it. It worked once and then it stopped and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless interfaces aren't like normal ethernet interfaces- often you can't use tcpreplay with them because the driver doesn't support injecting raw frames.  And in cases where raw frames are allowed, the driver may do additional sanity checks to make sure the frames should be sent out that interface (validating MAC addresses for example).

Also, the LED may or may not light up when the NIC sends a frame using the raw interface, so that might not be a good way to debug.

Comment: ok, but if I use wireshark I see that the packet is transmitted, I even tried with forging a get request with scapy but I still got the same result even forging the syn ack packets